# How to use i18n-iso-countries in Angular 6

Tags: angular

In my Angualr 6 application I am trying to convert country codes to country names using i18n-iso-countries library (JavaScript).
I installed it using npm

> npm -i i18n-iso-countries

Then in my component I imported it like this:

> import * as i18IsoCountries from 'i18n-iso-countries';

And I am using it like this:

```
  let valueName = '';
  tmpArr = tmpArr.map((e) => {
      const tmp = e.split('_')[1];
      console.log('tmp: ' + tmp);
      // console.log(i18IsoCountries);
      valueName = i18IsoCountries.getName(tmp, 'en');
      return tmp;
    }
```

However valueName is undefined.

I also created similar setup in [Stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezcrwc)
You can see that output from getName is undefined but output from getAlpha2Codes() returns value.

Comment: How do you create a list with all countries and codes? So as key-value pair maybe or even not as object first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just found out that language needs to be registered. The documentation is a little confusing

> If you use i18n-iso-countries with Node.js your are done.

But you **do** need to register the languages that you want to use.

So in Angular 6 you need to:

> npm install i18n-iso-countries --save

Then in your component:

`import * as i18nIsoCountries from 'i18n-iso-countries';`

And then in ngOnInit()

`i18nIsoCountries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));`

Answer (score 5):

Import Locale File is missing.
i18nIsoCountries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));

Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbmbwq

Comment: i18n-iso-countries/langs/ar.json => Not working for Arabic. Always undefined.